# Angular unit test for eventHandler

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I have an elment in the UI with event handers added like

```
[eventHandlers]="eventHandlers"
```

My ts file has this eventHandlers

```
eventHandlers= new Map<
    string,
    (event?: service.ICustomEvent<any>) => void
  >([
      ['rendered',
      async () => {
        console.log('rendered');
        //codes
      },
    ],
    ['loaded',
      async () => {
        console.log('loaded');
        //codes
      },
    ]
]);
```

Now I want to write unit tests for these event handers. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: you should use output bindings, not misuse input bindings

Comment: This is on a report component where I dont have control on inside elements and that is why events are handled in this way.@MarianTheisen

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
const renderedFunction = eventHandlers.get('rendered'); // get function
await renderedFunction(); // call it

const loadedFunction = eventHandlers.get('loaded');
await loadFunction();
```